# Angular v9 to v10 update error `Cannot add the "@Injectable" decorator to providers which don't have that decorator set.`

Tags: angular, angular9, angular10, angular-ivy

I'm updating an Angular library version from `v9.1.13` to `v10.2.5`, but getting the following error: `Migration failed: Could not find any tsconfig file. Cannot add the "@Injectable" decorator to providers which don't have that decorator set.`

[image]

I searched for Angular resources mentioned along with error: https://v9.angular.io/guide/migration-injectable, but it didn't help much as library is already following the required structure.

Similar kind of question is still unanswered on SO: [Angular version update giving an error - Migration failed: Could not find any tsconfig file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68177115/angular-version-update-giving-an-error-migration-failed-could-not-find-any-ts)

If anyone has already gone through alike problem and found the solution, help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Did you go through the upgrade steps here: https://update.angular.io/?l=2&v=9.0-10.0

Comment: Yes. The last step in "Before Updating" section redirects to same Angular Docs link as I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: maybe you could try explaining your problem on the github of angular

Comment: @GouravPokharkar are you able to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you update `Angular 9` to `Angular 10` like this below?

```
ng update @angular/core@10 @angular/cli@10 --force
```

If above approach does not work try disabling Ivy engine in `tsconfig.json` file:

> In case if you are using some outdated package which is not compatible with Ivy.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {"enableIvy": false}
```

Comment: I'm updating a specific library (`ng2-dnd`) which wasn't supporting ivy. I could update it to v9 with `"angularCompilerOptions": { compilationMode: "partial" }` as recommended by Angular. I just got issue as `NG2003: No suitable injection token for parameter`, so I followed `https://angular.io/errors/NG2003#debugging-the-error` link. It got resolved after I added `@Inject()` for constructor parameters and library is also working fine.

Comment: Current problem is just with migration from v9 to v10 as mentioned in question below. I'm getting issue in `ng update` step only, so it doesn't have anything to do with `compilationMode` or `enableIvy` at the time of migration.
It's failing at migration and also error is not pointing out the code where the issue lies.